# C# Using block context, within another using block context

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

I get the following error

> Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been
>   disabled. Please enable DTC for network access in the security
>   configuration for MSDTC using the Component Services Administrative
>   tool.

When I try to do the following

```
using (DataOneContext context1 = new DataOneContext())
{
     code...

     using (DataTwoContext context2 = new DataTwoContext())
     {
          more code...
     }
}
```

When I separate them, the code works.  But to have things simple, it'd be easier for one to be in the other.  Is it possible?

I would like to avoid enabling MSDTC.

DataOneContext and DataTwoContext are the tables in the DBML file (sorry I don't know the technical term).

Each context is connecting to a different server.

Comment: What is a DataOneContext or a DataTwoContext.  We have no idea.

Comment: @Hogan - It's the tables in the DBML.

Comment: DBML implies LINQ to SQL as your ORM, correct? Are they actually two seperate DBML files or are they two seperate tables in the same file?

Comment: It seems like each one is creating a transaction. A single transaction by itself is fine. However when you have multiple simultaneous transactions (by nesting them), the transactions have to be coordinated and MSDTC is the transaction coordinator. Exactly how would you like to solve the problem?

Comment: @Robert MacLean, they're two different DBML files.

Comment: @Gabe, is it inadvisable to enable the MSDTC everyone time the method is executed?  Is it possible to enable and disable using C# code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this by sharing the connection (assuming the same server). Transactions automatically get promoted to distributed transactions when they use different connections.

```
using (DataOneContext context1 = new DataOneContext()) 
{ 
     code... 

     using (DataTwoContext context2 = new DataTwoContext(context1.Connection)) 
     { 
         more code....
     } 
}
```

Comment: @Fritos - then how do you expect to avoid doing a distributed transaction?  Follow the error message's advice and setup/enable MSDTC to work between the two servers and your client.

Comment: @Fritos - the only other way that I know is to set up a linked server configuration between your servers, then only connect to one of them using the method I describe.  That only avoids having to include the web server in the MSDTC configuration, though, I think.